# To Print each stage of Bubble sort in Python3.6

Tags: python-3.x

Sort the given set of numbers using Bubble Sort. The first line of the input contains the number of elements, the second line of the input contains the numbers to be sorted. In the output print the status of the array at the 3rd iteration and the final sorted array in the given format

```
alist=[]
def bubble_sort(alist):
    for i in range(len(alist) - 1, 0, -1):
        no_swap = True
        for j in range(0, i):
            if alist[j + 1] < alist[j]:
                alist[j], alist[j + 1] = alist[j + 1], alist[j]
                no_swap = False
        if no_swap:
            return
n=int(input()) 
for i in range(n):
    alist.append(int(input()))
alist = [int(x) for x in alist]
bubble_sort(alist)
print('Sorted array: ', end='\n')
for i in alist:
    print(i,end=" ")
```

Test Case 1

7

64

34

25

12

22

11

90

Expected Output:
It should print the following 3 lines

12 22 11 25 34 64 90

Sorted array:

11 12 22 25 34 64 90

Test Case 2

8

14

83

25

47

9

77

1

0

Expected Output:
It should print the 3 following lines

14 9 25 1 0 47 77 83

Sorted array:

0 1 9 14 25 47 77 83

Comment: Okay. You've copied the problem statement. What exactly is *your question*?

Comment: Could you present you function in a way so that it is easier to follow its flow? it will help us (once you will have told us your question).

Comment: My problem is that the above code is getting me the final sorted array, but am unable to print the third iteration of the bubble sort.Can you please suggest some alterations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add in your for loop a print when you reach the third iteration

```
alist=[]
def bubble_sort(alist):
    number_of_iterations = 0
    for i in range(len(alist) - 1, 0, -1):
        no_swap = True
        for j in range(0, i):
            if alist[j + 1] < alist[j]:
                alist[j], alist[j + 1] = alist[j + 1], alist[j]
                no_swap = False
        if i == len(alist) - 3:
            print(*alist) # Using the unpacking operator for pretty print, if you are in python2 you can print it this way : " ".join(map(str, alist))
        if no_swap:
            return
n=5
alist = [7, 64, 34, 25, 12, 22, 11, 90]
bubble_sort(alist)
print('Sorted array: ', end='\n')
for i in alist:
    print(i,end=" ")
```

Comment: thankyou ,BlueSheepToken for the answer, it worked and appreciate it

Comment: Do not hesitate to accept the answer :) (Clicking on the tick aside my answer)

Comment: Very sorry for that , I am a new user hence will take time to get accustomed to the rules, thank-you for the answer.